# Kotlin. Как связать Android приложение с сайтом расположенным на своём сервере?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, get, retrofit

Прошу помощи, подсказки! Есть [**сайт**](https://most.ucdoss.ru), который расположен на собственном сервере, в нём минимальный функционал, а именно:

1. Страница авторизации, где пользователь заходит под своим номером телефона и паролем.
2. На самом сайте есть десяток обучающих видео, которые загружены на своём сервере.
3. На сайте зарегистрировано <100 человек.

Начал делать приложение, для телефонов с андроидом, воспользовался стандартными шаблонами в Android Studio (login Activity и Navigation Drawer Activity), работает и переходит на второе активити после авторазиции, даже если ввести рандомный логин и пароль.

ВОПРОС: Как связать авторизацию сайта с приложением, а так же, как сделать чтоб видео с сайта отображались в приложении.

*Всем огромное спасибо, с ув!*

Comment: Вам попроще или прям чтоб понастоящему?

Comment: Да как-нибудь по простому, чтоб работало и ладно, а дальше будет время - изучу.

Comment: используйте [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)

Comment: Спасибо! Пойду почитаю документацию!